# How to draw a web image by coreText

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a question about How to draw a web image  by **coreText**,because i don't know the size of web image
unless i download it.so I hope draw it dynamic. any idea?

Comment: Core Text? This is used to render text (unsurprisingly). You shouldn't be using it to render an image. Unless you're doing ascii image rendering?

Comment: sorry i know that should use render text, i want to know how to typesetting

Comment: It sounds like Eric wants to render text with an embedded image. Think, for example, a message with an emoticon image included. Eric would like to know how to tell Core Text the size of the image without actually downloading it.